# Link a shared library with kdevelop and CMake

Tags: cmake, kdevelop

Hello I have seen two post on this subject but I am still don't succeed in running my sample
(I am new with kdevelop and cmake so apologize for this pretty naive question)
I create in kdevelop a proj3 project and want to link a library so I create a second project projA within the proj3 directory

the projA CMakelist is
    project(proja)

```
set( lib_SOURCES Execute_Msg.cpp )

add_library(proja ${lib_SOURCES} )
```

the proj3 CMakelist is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(proj3)
link_directories(/pascal/pKD3/proj3/projA/build)
add_executable(proj3 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(proj3 libproja)
```

there is a libproja file in the /pascal/pKD3/proj3/projA/build directory, so I don't understand why I get the message /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibproja

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try
target_link_libraries(proj3 proja)
instead of
target_link_libraries(proj3 libproja).
The "lib" prefix is added automatically when searching the library.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I get the same message :/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lproja

Comment: Do you somehow add the library and the executable project together with an add_subdirectory call from a top-level project?

Comment: no I didn't do that,with the add_subdirectory it works thanks.